# Tomcat shuts down on its own

Tags: tomcat

The web application is deployed in Tomcat 6 with JRE 1.7. Sometimes Tomcat shuts down on its own with logs like below:

```
...
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:33)] [Thread-3] [INFO ] Scheduled scanning
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-3] [INFO ] Select table to query
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-3] [INFO ] SQL query: SELECT * FROM ...
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:33)] [Thread-11] [INFO ] Scheduled scanning
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-11] [INFO ] Select table to query
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,517] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-11] [INFO ] SQL query: SELECT * FROM ...
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,518] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:33)] [Thread-6] [INFO ] Scheduled scanning
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,518] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-6] [INFO ] Select table to query
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,518] [SomeDao(SomeDao.java:23)] [Thread-6] [INFO ] SQL query: SELECT * FROM ...
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,523] [org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ConnectionPool.shutdown(ConnectionPool.java:484)] [Shutdown Hook] [INFO ] : Shutting down 'bidbconn' pool immediately [Shutdown Hook]
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,529] [org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.PrototyperController.shutdown(PrototyperController.java:100)] [Shutdown Hook] [INFO ] : Stopping Prototyper thread
[2017-07-27 03:19:44,529] [org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.HouseKeeperController.shutdown(HouseKeeperController.java:107)] [Shutdown Hook] [INFO ] : Stopping HouseKeeper thread
July 27, 2017 3:19:44 A.M. org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9006
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
[2017-07-27 03:19:45,591] [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1042)] [Thread-62] [INFO ] : Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jul 27 02:44:29 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[2017-07-27 03:19:45,594] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:444)] [Thread-62] [INFO ] : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5f0f419c: defining beans [...]; root of factory hierarchy
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/app] registered the JBDC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/app] registered the JBDC driver [org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/app] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/app] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
July 27, 2017 3:19:45 A.M. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/app] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
...
```

I have no idea what goes wrong.

Comment: how you work with oracle? what connection pool mechanism and configuration?

Comment: @user7294900 Wrapper over Proxool